# How to use destructor to clear Linked List memory, without having valgrind errors? [Update: Operator Overload help]

Tags: c++, debugging, memory-management, linked-list, valgrind

I'm trying to debug my code through valgrind, and I see `invalid free()` issue. It seems my `frees` are more than my `allocs`.

The valgrind output is as follows:

```
==11814== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==11814== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==11814== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==11814== Command: ./doublyLinkedList -v --leak-check=full
==11814== 
==11814== Invalid read of size 8
==11814==    at 0x400A7A: DLinkedList::~DLinkedList() (doublyLinkedList.cpp:92)
==11814==    by 0x400DD1: main (doublyLinkedList.cpp:175)
==11814==  Address 0x5a87c88 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==11814==    at 0x4C2B1C6: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==11814==    by 0x400A90: DLinkedList::~DLinkedList() (doublyLinkedList.cpp:93)
==11814==    by 0x400DC5: main (doublyLinkedList.cpp:178)
==11814==  Block was alloc'd at
==11814==    at 0x4C2A0FC: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==11814==    by 0x4009B5: DLinkedList::DLinkedList(int) (doublyLinkedList.cpp:57)
==11814==    by 0x400D90: main (doublyLinkedList.cpp:175)
==11814== 
==11814== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==11814==    at 0x4C2B1C6: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==11814==    by 0x400A90: DLinkedList::~DLinkedList() (doublyLinkedList.cpp:93)
==11814==    by 0x400DD1: main (doublyLinkedList.cpp:175)
==11814==  Address 0x5a87c80 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==11814==    at 0x4C2B1C6: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==11814==    by 0x400A90: DLinkedList::~DLinkedList() (doublyLinkedList.cpp:93)
==11814==    by 0x400DC5: main (doublyLinkedList.cpp:178)
==11814==  Block was alloc'd at
==11814==    at 0x4C2A0FC: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==11814==    by 0x4009B5: DLinkedList::DLinkedList(int) (doublyLinkedList.cpp:57)
==11814==    by 0x400D90: main (doublyLinkedList.cpp:175)
==11814== 
==11814== 
==11814== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11814==     in use at exit: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==11814==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 4 frees, 72,752 bytes allocated
==11814== 
==11814== LEAK SUMMARY:
==11814==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11814==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11814==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11814==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==11814==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11814== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==11814== 
==11814== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==11814== ERROR SUMMARY: 4 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

For reference, my Doubly Linked List code is as follows:
(I understand I'm not freeing the reverse pointers, but even before I could get to it, I can't seem to get the one way free.)

```
#include <iostream>

class Node {
  friend class DLinkedList;
private:
  Node *_pPrev;
  Node *_pNext;
  int _data;

public:
  Node(): _pPrev(nullptr), _pNext(nullptr) { }
  Node(int d): _data(d), _pPrev(nullptr), _pNext(nullptr) { }
  Node(int d, Node *p, Node *n): _data(d), _pPrev(p), _pNext(n) { }

  // Getters
  const int getData() {
    return _data;
  }

  const Node* getPreviousNode() {
    return _pPrev;
  }

  const Node* getNextNode() {
    return _pNext;
  }
};

class DLinkedList {
private:
  Node *_pHead;
  Node *_pTail;

public:
  DLinkedList();
  DLinkedList(int d);
  DLinkedList(Node *n);
  DLinkedList(const DLinkedList &dLList); // Copy Constructor
  ~DLinkedList();  // Destructor

  const DLinkedList operator+(const DLinkedList &dLList) const;
  DLinkedList& operator=(const DLinkedList &dLList); // Assignment operator overload

  void listDisplay();
  void reverseListDisplay();
  void append(int d);
  void append(Node *n);
  void append(const DLinkedList &dLList);
};

DLinkedList::DLinkedList() {
  _pHead = _pTail = nullptr;
}

DLinkedList::DLinkedList(int d) {
  _pHead = new Node(d, nullptr, nullptr);
  _pTail = _pHead;
}

DLinkedList::DLinkedList(Node *n) {
  _pHead = n;
  _pTail = _pHead;
}

DLinkedList::DLinkedList(const DLinkedList &dLList) {
  _pHead = dLList._pHead;
  _pTail = dLList._pTail;
}

DLinkedList& DLinkedList::operator=(const DLinkedList &dLList) {
  return *this;
}

DLinkedList::~DLinkedList() {
  while (Node *currentHead = _pHead) {
    Node *next = currentHead->_pNext;
    _pHead = currentHead->_pNext;
    delete currentHead;
  }
}

const DLinkedList DLinkedList::operator+(const DLinkedList &dLList) const {
  DLinkedList temp(*this);

  temp._pTail->_pNext = dLList._pHead;
  temp._pTail->_pNext->_pPrev = temp._pTail;
  temp._pTail = dLList._pTail;

  return temp;
}

void DLinkedList::listDisplay() {
  if (_pHead == nullptr) {
    std::cout << "List is empty!" << std::endl;
    return;
  }

  Node *it = _pHead;
  while (it != nullptr) {
    std::cout << it->_data << std::endl;
    it = it->_pNext;
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

void DLinkedList::reverseListDisplay() {
  if (_pHead == nullptr) {
    std::cout << "List is empty!" << std::endl;
    return;
  }

  Node *it = _pTail;
  while (it != nullptr) {
    std::cout << it->_data << std::endl;
    it = it->_pPrev;
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

void DLinkedList::append(int d) {
  if (_pHead == nullptr) {
    _pHead = new Node(d, nullptr, nullptr);
    _pTail = _pHead;
    return;
  }

  Node *n = new Node(d, _pTail, nullptr);
  _pTail->_pNext = n;
  _pTail = _pTail->_pNext;
}

void DLinkedList::append(Node *n) {
  if (_pHead == nullptr) {
    _pHead = n;
    _pTail = _pHead;
    return;
  }

  _pTail->_pNext = n;
  _pTail->_pNext->_pPrev = _pTail;
  _pTail = _pTail->_pNext;
}

void DLinkedList::append(const DLinkedList &dLList) {
  _pTail->_pNext = dLList._pHead;
  _pTail->_pNext->_pPrev = _pTail;
  _pTail = dLList._pTail;
}

int main() {
  DLinkedList listA(10);
  listA.append(20);

  DLinkedList listB(listA);
}
```

I'm following the [Rule of Three](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Can someone please point towards the right direction to understand why I'm seeing this? I've researched and tried many different implementations, but some just break it even worse. Specifically, the problem seems to occur when `DLinkedList listB(listA);` is called inside `main()`.

**UPDATE**:
Thanks to the help from you guys, I was able to figure out the problem. But now, in extension, I'm running into similar issues with the operator overloads. Thank you for helping me out. Would appreciate some "pointers" in the right direction. Valgrind and code posted below:

```
==30270== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==30270== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==30270== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==30270== Command: ./doublyLinkedList
==30270== 
10
20
30

30
20
10

10
20
30
10
20
30

==30270== Invalid read of size 8
==30270==    at 0x400C31: DLinkedList::~DLinkedList() (doublyLinkedList.cpp:119)
==30270==    by 0x400F83: main (doublyLinkedList.cpp:189)
==30270==  Address 0x5a87da8 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==30270==    at 0x4C2B1C6: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30270==    by 0x400C47: DLinkedList::~DLinkedList() (doublyLinkedList.cpp:120)
==30270==    by 0x400F77: main (doublyLinkedList.cpp:193)
==30270==  Block was alloc'd at
==30270==    at 0x4C2A0FC: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30270==    by 0x400A57: DLinkedList::DLinkedList(DLinkedList const&) (doublyLinkedList.cpp:73)
==30270==    by 0x400F2B: main (doublyLinkedList.cpp:189)
==30270== 
==30270== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==30270==    at 0x4C2B1C6: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30270==    by 0x400C47: DLinkedList::~DLinkedList() (doublyLinkedList.cpp:120)
==30270==    by 0x400F83: main (doublyLinkedList.cpp:189)
==30270==  Address 0x5a87da0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==30270==    at 0x4C2B1C6: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30270==    by 0x400C47: DLinkedList::~DLinkedList() (doublyLinkedList.cpp:120)
==30270==    by 0x400F77: main (doublyLinkedList.cpp:193)
==30270==  Block was alloc'd at
==30270==    at 0x4C2A0FC: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30270==    by 0x400A57: DLinkedList::DLinkedList(DLinkedList const&) (doublyLinkedList.cpp:73)
==30270==    by 0x400F2B: main (doublyLinkedList.cpp:189)
==30270== 
==30270== 
==30270== HEAP SUMMARY:
==30270==     in use at exit: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==30270==   total heap usage: 11 allocs, 13 frees, 73,944 bytes allocated
==30270== 
==30270== LEAK SUMMARY:
==30270==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30270==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30270==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30270==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==30270==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30270== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==30270== 
==30270== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==30270== ERROR SUMMARY: 6 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Only posting the operator overloads, copy constructor, and destructor:

```
DLinkedList::DLinkedList(const DLinkedList &dLList){

  Node *n1 = nullptr; // Current
  Node *n2 = nullptr; // Next

  if (dLList.pHead_ == nullptr) {
    pHead_ = nullptr;
  } else {
    pHead_ = new Node();
    pHead_->data_ = dLList.pHead_->data_;

    n1 = pHead_;
    n2 = dLList.pHead_->pNext_;
  }

  while (n2) {
    Node *prev = n1;
    n1->pNext_ = new Node();
    n1 = n1->pNext_;
    n1->pPrev_ = prev;
    n1->data_ = n2->data_;

    n2 = n2->pNext_;
  }

  pTail_ = n1;
  n1->pNext_ = nullptr;
}

DLinkedList& DLinkedList::operator=(const DLinkedList &dLList) {
  DLinkedList temp(dLList);
  std::swap(temp.pHead_, pHead_);
  return *this;
}

DLinkedList& DLinkedList::operator+=(const DLinkedList &dLList) {
  (*this).pTail_->pNext_ = dLList.pHead_;
  (*this).pTail_->pNext_->pPrev_ = (*this).pTail_;
  (*this).pTail_ = dLList.pTail_;
  return *this;
}

const DLinkedList DLinkedList::operator+(const DLinkedList &dLList) const {
  DLinkedList temp = *this;

  temp += dLList;
  return temp;
}

DLinkedList::~DLinkedList() {

  Node *currentHead = pHead_;
  Node *currentTail = pTail_;
  while (Node *currentHead = pHead_) {
    pHead_ = currentHead->pNext_;
    delete currentHead;
  }
  pHead_ = nullptr;
  pTail_ = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Take an A4/letter piece of paper, a pencil, and an eraser. Draw a doubly linked list with 3 elements. (Objects are rectangles, pointers are arrows). Draw another linked list with 2 elements. Now trace what `operator=` does (draw new rectangles and arrows and erase old ones). Now trace what happens when both get destroyed.

Comment: *I'm following the Rule of Three* -- You're supposed to create a **brand new**, self-standing linked list that has the same data as the original list, not share pointers between the two lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are "following" the Rule of Three but you haven't understood what the rules about at all:

```
DLinkedList::DLinkedList(const DLinkedList &dLList) {
    _pHead = dLList._pHead;
    _pTail = dLList._pTail;
}
```

This implementation is what the generated default constructor would do. You need to actually *copy* the elements. As is, you just copy the pointers and the destructors of both the copy and the original will `delete` the same elements.

Comment: Thank you! That certainly makes sense. I'm currently making the changes and excited to see how this goes. Will add an update soon.

Comment: Definitely fixed the valgrind issues as well. Thanks again!
Quick question: Does that mean my assignment and addition operator overload need to be changed as well?

Comment: @Bidyut: your assignment doesn't do anything. If you want to actually assign it obviously needs to change! You can leverage the copy constructor if also get a `swap()` operation: `L& L::operator= (L tmp) { this->swap(tmp); return *this; }`. You `operator+()` suffers from the same problem as your copy constructor. Again you can leverage the copy constructor but this time via a `splice()` operation.

Comment: Right! I attempted to use the swap-copy-idiom later, and I'm updating the post. Addition now seems to cause similar valgrind errors. This time, I checked to see that I'm not just copying pointers, but clearly I'm missing something. Could you take a look as well? Thanks

Comment: @Bidyut: In your addition you still copy just the pointers of the RHS to the LHS. You need to actually transfer them. Effectively, you need to create a copy of the RHS (e.g., using the copy constructor) and then [`splice()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice) the copied list into the appropriate position: adjust the pointers in the LHS and set the copy up to be empty.

Comment: I tried it by doing this:

1) Copy RHS: Using copy constr (Let's call it rhs)
2) Set (*this).tail->next to (rhs.head)
3) Set (*this).tail->next->prev to (current *this tail)
4) Set (*this).tail  to (rhs.tail).
5) Return *this.

Now, I'm actually creating a copy of the rhs, and setting the LHS pointers to use new rhs's pointers. So, I'm wondering, 

a) Why does it still not work
b) Do I need to go node by node
c) I don't have a custom iterator. splice() requires an iterator. I'm not using the list library. So, alternative?

Thanks

Comment: @Bidyut: copying the RHS is one step. The other step is rewiring the new list into the existing list and then rewiring the copy to not point to the elements anymore and look empty. Just copying the RHS into a temporary is, obviously, insufficient as this temporary will destroy its elements.

Comment: Oh bless the heavens, this worked! It's working with all the constructors and overloads! Thank you, Dietmar! You just made my week.